# using GlassFish 4.0 and getting No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql error

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jdbc, glassfish-4

the following error i am getting;

```
type Exception report

messageInternal Server Error

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/chh-cw
root cause

java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/chh-cw
```

the following is my project structure:

[image]

is this the correct path to put the external jars??

Answer (score 1):

It depends.  Who is actually creating the connection?  If your application code is directly, then the JAR belongs in WEB-INF/lib.  If your container is managing the connections through a JNDI resource, then the JAR needs to be in the *Glassfish* classpath, not WEB-INF/lib.

In Glassfish 3.x I put the JARs in `domain/lib/ext` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

yes - if you do your Connection in an may LoginServerlet...
with Code like this:

this.conn = DriverManager.getConnection(getConnString());

you only have to copy the mysql..connector.jar to the WEB-Inf/lib Folder or your Domain.